# django form not calling html page

Tags: django, forms, httpresponse

I am learning django and started with just a small login authentication system. I created the html page for login :

```
<html>
    <title>Login</title>
    <body>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <form name="login" action = "/loginr/" method = "get">
                    USERNAME:<input type="text" name="uname"><br>
                    PASSWORD:<input type="password" name="passwd"><br>
                    <input type = "submit" value = "Login">
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
def index(request):
    return render(request,'login_page.html')
x=''
def process(request):
    global x
    x=request.GET
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/thanks/')
def thanks(request):
    return render(request, 'thanks.html')
```

my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns,url
from login import views

urlpatterns=patterns('',
            url(r'^$',views.index, name="index"),
            url(r'^loginr/',views.process),
            url(r'^login/thanks/',views.thanks)
    )
```

outermost mysite/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^login/', include('login.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^loginr/', include('login.urls')),
url(r'^login/thanks/',include('login.urls')),
)
```

The above codes show no error. But when i fill the login form and click login, the page itself reloads. I want the "thanks.html" to load. What is the mistake am I doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `views.py`, you didn't import `HttpResponseRedirect`.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
```

---

**UPDATE**

Change `mysite/urls.py` as follow:

```
...
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include('login.urls')),
)
```

Change `login/urls.py` as foolow:

```
...
urlpatterns=patterns('',
    url(r'^loginr/?$',views.process),
    url(r'^login/thanks/?$',views.thanks)
    url(r'^login/?$',views.index, name="index"),
)
```

Comment: Adding this doesn't change anything. Moreover, if that was an error, i would have got some error right?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh, That means .. `process` is not called at all.

Comment: No. When i first made a mistake in that function, I got an error. (i.e), instead of `global x; x=request.GET;` i directly used `global x=request.GET` and got a syntax error

Comment: @AswinMurugesh, Syntax error is raise regardless of the function call. Add some log or `print` in `process` function and see whether it is printed.

Comment: @AswinMurugesh, Can you show the outermost `urls.py` file content?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh, See **UPDATE** in my answer.

Comment: That gives me a page not found error. Now its not loading even the login page

Comment: The url of login page: `127.0.0.1:8000/login`. After i press login, the url changes to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/loginr/?uname=admin&passwd=admin`

Comment: @AswinMurugesh, Also change `login/urls.py`.

Comment: Ya the url changes to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/loginr/login/thanks/login/thanks/login/thanks/login/thanks/login/thanks/login/thanks/login/thanks/login/thanks/login/thanks/login/thanks/login/thanks/login/thanks/login/thanks/login/thanks/login/thanks/login/thanks/login/thanks/login/thanks/login/thanks/login/thanks/`. I get a `problem loading page` error now

Comment: Ya problem solved. Thank you so much. One more thing.. I had to change `login/thanks` to `loginr/login/thanks` . Now it works fine

Comment: @AswinMurugesh, Instead of using hard-coded url like `/login/thanks` use `urlresolver.reverse` in views / `url` tag in template.